# HealthBar Actionscript

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Here's my answer to this question for the healthbar:

```
function HealthBar() {
    var percentHP = currentRaidBossHP / maxRaidBossHP
    RaidBoss_HealthBar.barColor.scaleX = percentHP;
}

function BarrierHitted(): void {
    currentRaidBossHP -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 100001);
    if (currentRaidBossHP <= 0)
    {
        percentageHP_txt.visible = false;
    }
    HealthBar();
}
```

Comment: **(1)** Either you want [HitTestPoint](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()) or the other **HitTestObject**. Use them to check if graphics are touching (or so called "intersecting"). **(2)** In your shown code it is not obvious what is **the Pong** and what is **the gauge**, so who can answer your question? **(3)** You can [update the code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72068840/edit) with what you tried for Hit Testing.

Comment: **(1)** OK. I see the update. What is the problem? The code looks like it should work. Maybe change from `.scaleX` to using `.width`. **(2)** You don't need 3 ways to call the same function `updateHealthBar`. Remove these two things... You don't need `Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateHealthBar` and also you don't need to call it from the hit test (since it is called by **BarrierHitted** function).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: _"How do I do that?"_ Not enough information here. You are not telling me which part is difficult...

Comment: When the pong hits the barrier, the healthbar is decreasing.

Comment: _"Argument count mismatch on updateHealthBar()"_ See my **point (2)** from [5 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068840/healthbar-actionscript#comment127378911_72068840). Especially the part about **remove the EnterFrame line** because updateHealthBar is a function with no parameters so using enterframe is like saying `updateHealthBar ( with Event added );` but the function actually expects to be called as `updateHealthBar ( nothing in here )` so the solution is: **don't mix enterframe listener with updateHeathBar**

Comment: _"stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopSecret);"_ this will error because your code **did not add the event** but then your code tries to remove this same "not-added" event. It is null because it does not exist.

Comment: Any Ideas how to solve it?

Comment: That's a different Question to the healthbar issue. You need to try something and ask a new Question about that. The short version is don't put code on different frames (each Stage frame is like a new page so with code for that frame only). There should be a frame 97 **only if** you are making an animation/cartoon. If coding an app, then all code and graphics is on frame 1. Use movieclips if you need things to go to different frames. Use "cut/copy frame" options to move frames from Stage timeline & paste into a MovieClip's timeline

Comment: Try this: **(1)** Create an MC same width/height size as Stage area. **(2)** Select all frames in timeline (ignore layer with MC) and use "cut frames" option then double click the MC to enter its timeline. Now use "paste frames" option. In Main timeline you have 2 layers, one for ALL code and one for the MC. Give the MC an Instance name. Replace all `gotoAnd` with `myMCname.gotoAnd` in the code. Try something and you'll see. Also learn to use options like `addChild` to add "screens" when needed or `.visible=true` when you want an object to be visible. Practice, practice and more practice.

Comment: How to do it? Can you give some tips?

Comment: **(1)** On your timeline what happens if you right-click on a **keyframe** (is black dot), do you see [options like this image](https://live.staticflickr.com/7249/6952063618_184cd04a84_c.jpg)? If yes, that's how you can cut frames and later in some MC's timeline, you can paste the copied/cut frames. **(2)** To create an MC just make a box shape (rectangle) with a fill color but no outline color. The box is same size as Stage area. Select the box and right-click to see option _"Convert to MovieClip"_ (and then in next shown pop-up, choose Top-left **registration**, not central)

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: _"I don't get it"_ You never said which part is difficult. Is it really difficult to draw a box shape (rectangle)? It's just pressing [this button](https://flylib.com/books/3/389/1/html/2/files/02fig13.gif). **(2)** Okay if you don't get it... Maybe just delete the line about `stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopSecret);`? That way you won't get error. **(3)** Best thing is to just stop using other people's code and just **make your own practice projects**. Think about how you cannot even draw a shape (a box) and fix that. Practice making shapes and converting that into MovieClip.

Comment: The whole part. Because I don't know how to solve this:    
if(ProtodermisEntity.Stunned == 110){
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopSecret);
                gotoAndStop("gameover_Secret");
                sound_channel.stop();
                return;
            }

Comment: **(1)** Please give **useful information**... You say _"How to solve this"_ but you never say what is wrong with it. Did you get an error that needs solving? if yes then tell that information. **I cannot see your screen**. **(2)** What happens if you delete that whole part of `IF` statement. Now is the **healthbar** decreasing correctly with no errors? Is your question now solved?

Comment: No, I still have an error...

Comment: Ok. When you are ready just tell me what the error says then we can move towards solving it.

Comment: I still have: "ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on BlowfishPong_fla::MainTimeline/updateHealthBar(). Expected 0, got 1."

Comment: Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72068840/edit) to show the code you are using.

Comment: Thanks for telling me you updated. If I did not check today I'd never know. Anyways your code is fine. The error means you are calling the function with some extra **1** thing added, but it wants **0** (no extra stuff added when doing function call). Think about it... If you have `function load( url )`, how many arguments does load want? Is it 1 parameter for the **url** to load? Yes!! Now look at your `function healthbar()` how many arguments it wants? I explained all this [1 week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068840/healthbar-actionscript?noredirect=1#comment127489898_72068840)

Comment: function updateHealthBar() is set, then I received this "1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value."

Comment: The code you showed is not assigning any "non-reference" value. Also if the only code you have is `function updateHealthBar(): void { ... etc` then it should error because you did not create variables like `var currentRaidBossHP`. Error should say "currentRaidBossHP is not defined". I don't know how you just wrote one function but you get strange errors (like you get no error for the undefined vars (is very strange), but you got new errors about something that your shown code is not even doing).

Comment: Also did you even read my Answer below from 10 days ago? I showed you 10 days ago how to use `updateHealthBar();`. See how in my code it is used from only inside `BarrierHitted()` function.

Comment: Ok, I need these steps to fix these:                                                                                     1. //# bad idea to move Stage to another frame, good luck with future problems
2. //# should be... someMC.gotoAndStop (where someMC has frame label "gameover_Secret")

Comment: Stage frames has nothing to do with "healthbar decreasing" issue. You are here to **solve the problem of hit detection** and how to reduce the size of healthbar if a hit is detected. If my Answer helped you to achieve that part then mark it as correct for others to find same Answer. You can up-vote it if it was useful to you. After that you can ask a new Question (for new Answers) about this other frames issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: *"When the pong hits the barrier, the healthbar is decreasing."*

**Solution**: You need to use HitTesting. Use EnterFrame to check "hits" every moment.

Try this code setup.

```
var RaidLives :uint = 3;
var maxRaidBossHP :uint = 5000;
var currentRaidBossHP :int = maxRaidBossHP;
var percentRaidBossHP :Number  = -1.0; 


//# use an EnterFrame function to check for collision
//# EnterFrame runs EVERY frame-per-second (FPS)
//# if FPS is 30 then EnterFrame checks 30 times for every 1 second

stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, check_for_Collision );

function check_for_Collision (evt :Event) 
{
    if ( ( ProtodermisEntity.LifeAura.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) ) == true ) 
    {
        trace( ">> Barrier was collided ... " )
        
        //# test without using IF statement
        BarrierHitted();
        updateTextFieldsSecret();
        
        //# Dont know if this code below works or not
        //# use it after testing without IF...
        
        /*
        if (ballSpeedXSecret > 0) 
        {
            ballSpeedXSecret *= -1;
            ballSpeedYSecret = calculateBallAngleSecret(ProtodermisEntity.y, blowfishPong.y);
            
            BarrierHitted();
            updateTextFieldsSecret();
        }
        */
    }
}

function BarrierHitted(): void 
{
    currentRaidBossHP -= 10;
    
    if (currentRaidBossHP <= 0)
    {
        ProtodermisEntity.gotoAndStop(6);
        if(ProtodermisEntity.Stunned == 110)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopSecret);
            
            sound_channel.stop();
            
            //# bad idea to move Stage to another frame, good luck with future problems
            //# should be... someMC.gotoAndStop (where someMC has frame label "gameover_Secret")
            gotoAndStop("gameover_Secret"); 
            
            //# cannot return anything if you got "void" setting for  your function
            //return;
        }
    }
    
    //# update gauge or health, because barrier was hit.
    updateHealthBar();
}

function updateHealthBar(): void 
{
    percentRaidBossHP = currentRaidBossHP / maxRaidBossHP;
    RaidBoss_HealthBar.barColor.scaleX = percentRaidBossHP;
}
```

Comment: Try as `var percentRaidBossHP :Number = -1.0; ` where you replace the **int** with **Number** in the top part of code. That should fix the healthbar issue. I forgot you were doing fractions (by using `.scaleX` instead of using `.width` which works with Integers). PS: An **int** type is a whole number like 1, 2 or 3, but **Number** type can have fractions like 0.5, 1.75 or 2.5678 etc...